# How to make a HTTP request using Node.js upon user input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronization

So I started this simple project in node.js where the client sends a POST request containing in it's body a windows CMD command.

The server receives the POST request, extracts the CMD command, and after running it, responds with the output of that command.

This worked fine when I had one request being sent out, but then I set up a system to repeatedly ask the user for the command and then send the POST request with the inputted command as it's body.

Here is the client-side code for this: (server side not included as it's irrelevant)

```
var http = require("http");
var readline = require("readline");
var rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);

var options = {
    hostname: "localhost",
    port: 3001,
    path: "/",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain",    // all command must be string
        "Content-Length": 0   // changes based on what the command is
    }
};

function requestCommand(hostname, port, command) {

    // Some of the options of the request need to be changed based on
    // what the command is
    options.hostname = hostname;
    options.port = port;
    options.headers["Content-Length"] = command.length;

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        console.log(`Got response. Status code: ${res.statusCode}`);

        var resData = "";
        res.setEncoding("utf-8");

        res.on("data", function(chunk){
            resData += chunk
        });

        res.on("end", function(){
            return resData;
        })

    })

    req.on("error", function (e){
        return "\n\n\n ---------------\nERROR OCCURED IN THE REQUEST.\nREQUEST NOT SENT\n--------------" + e.stack;

    })

    req.write(command);
    req.end();
}

rl.setPrompt("What command would you like to request from the server?: ");
rl.prompt();

rl.on("line", function(data){
    if (data === "exit") {
        console.log("\n\n\Exiting appplication...\n\n");
        process.exit();
    } else {
        console.log("processing..");
        var out = requestCommand("localhost", 3001, data);
        console.log(`\n\n${out}\n\n`);
        rl.prompt();
    }
});
```

If I run this without creating the server first, instead of getting the error message, I get `undefined`.

Currently, I think this is because the requestCommand function ends before the error is handled (before the `error` event is emitted and the callback function that returns the error is called), since the callback function for http.request is obviously asynchronous, and before the server responds or an error is emitted, the function ends and hence return nothing (`undefined`)

So my question is: Can I keep that function running until the asynchronous command is done?

Or if this is not possible, is there a different approach to this? How would you send requests to this server upon a certain event fired by the user, such as data input?

**EDIT:** I am really not interested in using a 3rd party modules as I already can. This project is really pointless and only here for me to learn, so I am only using core modules for this. More specifically, I am only using HTTP for making the requests (not sync-request, e.t.c..)

Comment: I am pretty new hear, so if I'm not making any sense, please ask for clarification or point out what part of my question should I improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requestCommand` has to return a promise that gets resolved with `resData` and rejected on error:

```
 function requestCommand(hostname, port, command) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // immeadiately return a Promise that can be resolved/rejected later
    // Some of the options of the request need to be changed based on
    // what the command is
    options.hostname = hostname;
    options.port = port;
    options.headers["Content-Length"] = command.length;

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
      console.log(`Got response. Status code: ${res.statusCode}`);

      var resData = "";
      res.setEncoding("utf-8");

      res.on("data", function(chunk){
          resData += chunk
      });

      res.on("end", function(){
          resolve(resData); // resolve, return won't work here
      });
    });

    req.on("error", function (e){
      reject(e); // reject here, don't handle it
    });

    req.write(command);
    req.end();
   });
}
```

That way, you can simply make the request handler `async` and then `await` the function call:

```
rl.on("line", async function(data){ // make the function async so that we can work with promises more easily
  if (data === "exit") {
    console.log("\n\n\Exiting appplication...\n\n");
    process.exit();
  } else {
    console.log("processing..");
    try {
      var out = await requestCommand("localhost", 3001, data); // "await" lets async code look like sync code, but it is still async
       console.log(`\n\n${out}\n\n`);
    } catch(e) { // the reject() call will end up here
      console.log("invalid command " + e.stack); // handle here
    }
    rl.prompt();
}
});
```

Comment: Can I just clarify, the function returns a promise which you can then await in an async function till it resolves or rejects. Correct?

Comment: @dennis exactly